# Twisted Connections

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, cryptic-clues, connect-wall

<sub>This is an entry into the [Fortnightly Topic Challenge #36](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6372/fortnightly-topic-challenge-36-twisted-classics-1)</sub>

The following is an Only-Connect wall seen in the BBC TV series. You have to divide the 16 words into groups of 4 each satisfying a specific condition.

Now, before you complain, the 16 words aren't given. Instead, you have been given Cryptic Clues that clue the words.

Next, after getting the words, you find out the groups of 4 and the relations between the words in the respective groups. So, you should get 4 words/phrases as your answer(this is where the game normally stops).

However, I can't stop there. So, next, using those 4 words/phrases, you have to find out another 4 words/phrases(How, you ask? That's the *real puzzle*)

Your final job is to create another only-connect wall with those groups of 4 words/phrases as the connections.

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's my working so far, for the clues I've been able to figure out. I'll keep plugging away and update as I go.

Row 1:

> THICKENS (Stiffens: anagram of KITCHENS)
>  REVIEW (analyse: English ditch=REEN, six=VI, gives REVIEN, then left (West) instead of up (North)). Thanks to Clarkey for the final part of this one
>  HANDED (Helped: Hotel=H, AND, education=ED)
>  BACK (to sponsor: the rear of something is the back of it)

Row 2:

> LINE (railway track: Portuga-LINE-urope)
>  MASTER (leader: victory=MATE, small=S, real=R (currency))
>  STEVEN (Spielberg: anagram of EVENTS)
>  GRAVE (double straight). Solved by Persona

Row 3:

> TAPES (piece=PAT, written left=TAP, is in Spanish=ES). Solved by Stiv
>  TEMPERED (initial letters + PER + bEDs). Solved by aPaulT
>  PLAN (design: quiet=P, unending street=LANe)
>  SCOTLAND (S + COT + LAND). Solved by aPaulT

Row 4

> DOCK (COCK [pile of hay] with D replacing C). Solved by aPaulT
>  PARTY (celebrate: or participant gathering, double-straight)
>  TWIST (TWISTER [swindler], remove ER). Solved by Stiv
>  FLOW (current: no hesitation in river=FLOWer)

---

Part 2: Connections

> EVEN: Flow, Tempered, Handed, Steven(s). Solved by aPaulT
>  YARD: Dock, Scotland, Back, Grave
>  PLOT: Thickens, Line, Plan, Twist
>  RAVE: Master, Party, Review, Tapes. Solved by aPaulT

---

Part 3: Using the Connections

> Arrange the four 4-letter words into a square and read down the columns to reveal four new words. Solved by aPaulT.
>  PLOT
>  RAVE
>  EVEN
>  YARD

---

Part 4: A new wall

> [image: A new connecting wall]

Comment: Yes I think your answer for 1,2 is correct. English ditch is a revene and left instead of up is W (west - left) instead of N (Notrth - up)

Comment: @Clarkey252 good shout - think you mean **reen** is a ditch though :-) Just a typo I assume heh

Comment: I added another connection idea to my answer

Comment: @aPaulT not sure on that one - I did wonder about it myself, but PLOT/PLAN seems a bit tenuous and connecting walls tend to not have more than one "can be preceded with X" group. That said, 1,1 is a tough word to find a group for if it isn't that

Comment: @Joe yeah, that was my thinking - nothing else seems to go with 1,1

Comment: @aPaulT I think that connection is right, as I've just found another word-based one. At this point I'm assuming they're all wordy connections

Comment: Based on that I have an idea for how the next step of the puzzle works. (I've never done collaborative solving here before... should I keep adding bits to my answer or is there a better way?)

Comment: @aPaulT not really sure to be honest - it's been a while since I've been very active here :P What's your thinking? I can't help but notice the 3 we've found are four-letter words, and we'll have 4 of them

Comment: I've added a bit to my answer (it basically gives away the rest of the puzzle I guess though...)

Comment: @aPaulT good shout - I thought it might be along those lines but didn't have the fourth word yet. I've added 3 words to the new group, leaving one word missing from 3 groups. I'll keep working on them

Comment: Excellent work! Once you get the rest of the cryptic clues, I will accept this answer.

Comment: @Sid give Paul an upvote too, he did a not-insignificant chunk of it with me

Comment: I believe 2,4 is rot13(n zhygvcyr qrs sbe 'tenir', orybatf va gur tebhc sbe 'lneq')

Comment: @Persona I was trying to find the one which was that word, but didn't know the alternate meaning. Thanks :-)

Comment: @Joe Here's your final two missing clues: "ribbons' piece left is Spanish(5)" = rot13(gncrf, [fvapr cvrpr = cng (yvxr ohggre), jevgr vg yrsgjneqf v.r. 'gnc', gura nqq 'vf' va Fcnavfu (rf)] juvpu tbrf jvgu ENIR.) And "spin no hesitation in swindler(5)" = rot13(gjvfg [n fjvaqyre vf  gjvfgre, erzbir gur urfvgngvba (re)], juvpu tbrf jvgu CYBG.) Now go claim your green tick! :-)

Comment: @Stiv Well done!  :)

Answer (score 5):

A few answers to add to @Joe's list:

(1,3)

> HANDED (H and Ed.)

(3,2)

> TEMPERED (initial letters + PER + (b)ED(s)

(3,4)

> SCOTLAND (S + COT + LAND)

(4,1)

> DOCK (COCK [pile of hay] with D replacing C)

And a couple of possible ideas for connections:

> EVEN: even-handed, even-tempered, even Steven(s), Even Flow [Pearl Jam song]

and more tenuously

> UP: line up, thickens up, back up (but lots of words can be followed by up)

EDIT: another connection idea:

> PLOT: "the plot THICKENS...", plotLINE, plot/PLAN (synonyms)

Part 3: new groups of 4 (with one inferred):

> The connections are:
>
>  PLOT
>  RAVE*
>  EVEN
>  YARD
>
>  Reading down the columns gives the new words PREY/LAVA/OVER/TEND.

Comment: I was editing in 1,3 just as you posted, good shout on the others ones. Still working on the remaining ones :)

Comment: The first connection is correct! Well done. The second is not however.

Answer (score -1):

Partial one

> (1,1) is THICKENS
>  (2,3) is STEVEN
>  (1,4) is RARE
>  (2,1) is LINE
>  (4,2) is PARTY

and others to be followed.

Comment: I've no objection to partial answers in general, but I think this sort of tiny fraction answer should be discouraged. If you had solutions to all, or nearly all, of the clues, that would be a reasonable place to put a stake in the ground; but two of the 16? Not so much.

Comment: Just by way of context: When I wrote the above, MCN's answer had answers for exactly two of the clues. (Now it has answers for four of them, but I'm pretty certain one of them is wrong.)