# I was inspired to create an anagram puzzle

Tags: word, anagram

Inspired by @[QuantumTwinkie](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/34530/quantumtwinkie)'s anagram puzzles, I have created my own anagram puzzle. It has $20$ lines. Some are easy, some are hard, but whoever can find them all will deserve the tick $\color{green}{\checkmark}$.

> 1. The nurse at the orphanage went to the _________ to check up on the children, but when she walked through the door, she said, "My, what a _____ ____!"
> 2. Every time he used the telescope, he tried to tell his son that he was an __________, but the son just kept calling him a "____ ______".
> 3. "I ____ _ _____!" shouted William ___________.
> 4. Looking at that giant _____ in the sky, it looks like it _____ rain.
> 5. "As a witch, you have two _______," said the old woman. "Do you want to fly on a broom or make some _______?"
> 6. The ______ gnomes were in ______ of being knocked over by the cat.
> 7. A ____ is a type of food that has a ____ of tortilla folded over some mixtures of other food (e.g. beans, lettuce, tomatoes, etc).
> 8. Joe likes to think of the sun as the _____ of the solar system, and _____ as the mind.
> 9. The students in ___ _________ were unexpectedly greeted by the ____________.
> 10. It was not until the following week that I realised my secret _______ in the mysterious letter was actually _______... how strange.
> 11. Political parties decide the  _________ of candidates for upcoming _________.
> 12. "You have the right to be ______!" warned the officer. But the man pleaded, "______ to me! I have been framed!"
> 13. "Where's the flour?" Mary asked. "I need it to _______ the batter." But Joseph couldn't find it, though he could have sworn he left the bag in the _______.
> 14. She couldn't purchase the phone on eBay, as she had ___ ______ on her _____ ____.
> 15. After hours of searching, he finally found the book 'The _____ Eating Zombies' on the top _____.
> 16. He called her a "_____ ______" when she said that her painting of the _____ ______ was actually art.
> 17. They used a _________ to pull the cart of some of the instruments for the _________.
> 18. "I can't concentrate with a noisy ______," she explained, "which is why I always ____ __ homework."
> 19. Rumour has it that Cory ____ a fridge that makes ____.
> 20. He had yet to decide where he will ____ the treasure, but he was definitely keeping the ____ for himself.

---

**Edit:**

@[IanF1](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/2021/ianf1) found a solution to 2, that is not the original. Thus, there are two solutions to that. The same applies to how @[Philipp](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/48365/philipp) found a solution to 9. 
 
 
 
 After @[Kevorobin](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/51276/kevorobin) posted the first answer regarding the 16th line ([below](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/68998/i-was-inspired-to-create-an-anagram-puzzle/69220#69220)), I will provide a hint to make it easier.

16. He called her a "_____ ______" when she said that her painting of the _____ ______ was actually art, pretending that it didn't exist. Considering what he said, it was quite ironic. Nonetheless, the painting wasn't finished; she had yet to paint the station.

Comment: @QuantumTwinkie here is my anagram puzzle! Hope you enjoy! :D

Comment: I love the puzzle!

Comment: is no.16 still unsolved? curious about what it might be.

Comment: @ShahriarMahmudSajid yes, it is. I don't need to change the clues. They are all there. I thought it would have been not hard, but not too easy either. It seems like the contrary only remains...

Comment: #16 is tough because you can paint a picture of pretty much anything. So the second part doesn't really narrow it down.

Comment: @jafe it is the fact that someone is painting art and that person believes it is art when another person does not. Those are the clues.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Partial answer.

I found 1, 2, 3, 7, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 17, 18, 20.

@practiced_liar beat me on 4, 5, 6, 8, 19.

Unsolved: 16

1.

> DORMITORY, DIRTY ROOM

2.

> ASTRONOMER, MOON STARER

3.

> SEEK A PHRASE, SHAKESPEARE

4.

> CLOUD, COULD

5.

> OPTIONS, POTIONS

6.

> GARDEN, DANGER

7.

> TACO, COAT

8.

> HEART, EARTH

9.

> THE CLASSROOM, SCHOOLMASTER

10.

> ADMIRER, MARRIED

11.

> SELECTION, ELECTIONS

12.

> SILENT, LISTEN

13.

> THICKEN, KITCHEN

14.

> BAD CREDIT, DEBIT CARD

15.

> FLESH, SHELF

16.

> 

17.

> CARTHORSE, ORCHESTRA

18.

> FAMILY, FAIL MY

19.

> OWNS, SNOW

20.

> BURY, RUBY

Comment: It is unfortunate that I spent my last upvote on @practiced_liar 's answer, as all the words you suggested is correct! All you need is to solve the unsolved :D

Comment: Another option for 9: the race, teacher.

Comment: @Philipp Interesting alternative answer.

Comment: A silly alternative for the second half of 2: rot13(ebbfgre zna)

Comment: @IanF1 hahahah :D

Comment: @Philipp you are not wrong ;D

Comment: 10 is correct :)

Comment: Congratulations! $\color{green}{\checkmark}$ However, it is not over yet... I am awarding a $+50$ rep bounty for the solution to 16, as it still remains unsolved. Although I have accepted your answer, you can still apply if you wish :D

Comment: The anagram for $13$ is actually found the answer to [this question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/67364/twisted-connections?rq=1). I'll try to make/find some more anagrams not commonly found in this community... which means I am making another anagram puzzle (regardless of my progress  being deleted for my fourth one)! If you like these puzzles, stay tuned :D

Answer (score 5):

Partial answer.

4.

> CLOUD, COULD

5.

> OPTIONS, POTIONS

6.

> GARDEN, DANGER

8.

> HEART, EARTH

10.

> ADMIRER, MARRIED

11.

> SELECTION, ELECTIONS

19.

> OWNS, SNOW

And finally for 16:

> CRANK ARTIST, TRAIN TRACKS

Comment: All of them are correct! :D

Comment: You made a great start, but unfortunately, I did not accept your answer; instead, I accepted @Riley 's answer... but there is more! I am awarding a +50 rep bounty for the solution to 16, as it still remains unsolved. Although your answer has not been accepted, you can still apply if you wish :D

Comment: @user477343 Did I get it right?

Comment: And finally for 16.... YES! You got it! That is correct! *(Throws confetti)* Congratulations! $\boxed{+50}$

Comment: Apologies if I did not see this before... but I am partly glad that I didn't, for otherwise @Kevorobin would not have shared his/her wonderful answer :D

Comment: No worries. It's actually Kevorobin and jamisans answers that put me on the right track (see what I did here?). Thanks for the great puzzle!

Comment: You're very welcome! I will be making a third anagram puzzle, but I can't seem to find/make some unique anagrams (or another $20$, to say the least). It might be about a week before I upload another one :)

Answer (score 3):

Came up with something funny for the 16th but I doubt it's the correct answer, haha.

> wannabe artist, banana twister

:D

Comment: For the first part, you got the second word correct; i.e., Rot13(negvfg). Although it is nearly correct, if this be the only/best answer for the 16th, you will receive the bounty award! :D

Comment: I am sorry to say this, but @practiced_liar has the correct answer... and received the bounty just about $15$ minutes ago. Looks like you *just* missed out. But, if you feel like you deserve a bounty, try answering one of my future riddles/puzzles, and if one of your answers are correct, I will award you a $50$ rep bounty to make up for this :D

Comment: Yep, I just noticed it and already deleted the comment (before you replied, sorry). Anyway, This is a really great puzzle and I will be more faster next time for sure!

Comment: Thank you very much! I am glad you enjoy it. That's the point of why I upload my puzzles: I don't care about the reputation, just as long as people like you enjoy it :D

Answer (score 2):

For 16, how about

> He called her a "CON ARTIST" when she said that her painting of the TRAIN COTS was actually art, pretending that it didn't exist. Considering what he said, it was quite ironic. Nonetheless, the painting wasn't finished; she had yet to paint the station.

Comment: Ooohhh, so close! For the second part, you got the first word correct; i.e., Rot13(genva). Also, Rot13(gur svefg jbeq va gur svefg cneg fgnegf jvgu P). You are now, in the lead! The $50$ rep bounty could be yours if somebody does not do one better :D

Answer (score 1):

For the 16th one

> Gaffing artist, graffiti angst

Comment: No not quite. Nice try, though :)