# I was inspired to create another anagram puzzle

Tags: word, anagram

Another anagram puzzle! Just like [my previous anagram puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/68998/i-was-inspired-to-create-an-anagram-puzzle), this one has $20$ lines. Some are easy, some are hard, but some can also be a little funny. Once again, credit to @[QuantumTwinkie](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/34530/quantumtwinkie)'s anagram puzzles, as they have served a heavy inspiration. Make sure to check them out, too!

> 1. His campfire stories do not _____ us anymore, so now nobody _____ about them either.
> 2. The word, "_________", is an anagram of *end*, but the word you seek is not "den" or "ned".
> 3. "That ______ always ______ himself on his web design, but I've never seen him catch a fly!" shouted the bird.
> 4. She would be a good _________ __ only she could be bothered reading the ___________ on everyone's resumés.
> 5. "Just because a book has a _____ cover, doesn't mean its _____ is about nature," said the librarian. "Read the title!"
> 6. The telescope did not see as far as the others, thus he was ______ to see the ______ in outer space.
> 7. There is a type of ______ matter referred to as "dark matter" that nobody really knows much about, which is probably why it is hardly mentioned in space ______, no matter how many issues there are.
> 8. The tiny jumping spider _____ from the _____ of the flower, landing on one of the man's shoes, before sadly crawling up his pants...
> 9. Tarzan is strong, swinging on the _____ of trees with _____ protruding from his big arms.
> 10. "This week, many kids have been wanting toy _______, so we have to _______ the store," said the manager.
> 11. "Don't do it!" David shouted. "You might get ______ by lightning! Just wait for the ______ to arrive, and then one of 'em can take you home."
> 12. How many times is he going to _____ about his giant _____? They do not interest me. I like trains!
> 13. "My favourite newspaper is the ___ ____ _____." I said. But my grandpa replied, "Nah, they are terrible. _______ _____ for them!" We laughed together, and I laughed even harder when he pulled out a banana.
> 14. She expected the ____ from the restaurant to taste really good. When the manager read her review, it said, "The food was awful and the restaurant was ____."
> 15. Sometimes, these anagram puzzles make me ____k too much, so I often ask for a ____.
> 16. I love to perform on stage, so I suppose I am quite a ________al person. But don't give me coffee — I am ________ than usual whenever I drink it, until people tell me to shut up.
> 17. I remember a _____ from a song that went something along the lines of, "only living to _____". I think it was in the musical, *Beauty and the Beast*, but I am not quite sure...
> 18. She got the picture of the firetruck, but the _______ was not __ _____. "Damn, he was a hottie," she muttered.
> 19. `_________! Welcome to the Electronic Gourmet Guide. Enter the password to begi———hahaha this site has been hacked!!!!!!! You must ______ "___" as the password for granted access!!!`
> 20. The manicure took forever! She was so slow at painting my _____, it was as if a _____ was painting them instead!

---

**Edit:**

Had to change one of the words in line 16 because according to Microsoft Word, it is not a word... :\ (along with other grammatical fix-ups)

@[ShahriarMahmudSajid](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/37211/shahriar-mahmud-sajid) found a solution to 19, that is not the original. Thus, there are two solutions to that.

Comment: Cool another anagram puzzle :D  this is the first time I am seeing this!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Starting from where [Gareth McCaughan](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/19114/gareth-mccaughan) left off

1

> SCARE/CARES

2

> IDENTICAL/ ITALIC END

3

> SPIDER / PRIDES

4

> NOMINATOR IF/ INFORMATION

5

> GREEN/GENRE

6

> UNABLE / NEBULA

7

> COSMIC/COMICS

8

> LEAPT / PETAL

9

> VINES/VEINS

10

> ROCKETS / RESTOCK

11

> STRUCK / TRUCKS

12

> BOAST/BOATS

13

> NEW YORK TIMES/MONKEYS WRITE

14

> MEAL/LAME

15

> THIN(k) / HINT

16

> THEATRIC(al)/ CHATTIER

17

> VERSE/SERVE

18

> FIREMAN/IN FRAME

19

> GREETINGS/ ENTER GIGS

20

> NAILS / SNAIL

$2$ and $16$ solved by [jafe](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/41973/jafe)

$7$ and $13$ by [sedrick](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/50424/sedrick)

Comment: I have included the word "enter" in 19 to Rot13(vaqvpngr gung gur jbeq vf abg bar bs gur nantenzf.) But your answer to 19 can serve an alternative, anyways. Also, you have all the solutions! Well done! :D

Comment: thanks, thinking about the alternate solution is it - Rot13(fvta rterg) ?

Comment: Nope. You were closer with the first proposal, the first word in particular :)

Comment: Well, congratulations! It has been $3$ days, and nobody has officially solved for $19$, so I will just say what the answer is here: Rot13(TERRGVATF / VAFREG "RTT". RTT fgnaqf sbe Ryrpgebavp Tbhezrg Thvqr.) And, I will tick *this* answer! $\;\color{green}{\checkmark}$

Comment: now that i see the answer, i'm like - why didn't i think of it, good one.

Answer (score 7):

16.

> I love to perform on stage, so I suppose I am quite a THEATRICal person. But don't give me coffee — I am CHATTIER than usual whenever I drink it, until people tell me to shut up.

Also 2.

> The word, "IDENTICAL", is an anagram of *end* [ITALIC END], but the word you seek is not "den" or "ned".

Comment: $(+1)$ Correct! (I always thought the first set of capitals was a word. Turns out it *is* a word according to this site, but not according to microsoft word...)

Comment: rot13(uggcf://jjj.qvpgvbanel.pbz/oebjfr/gurngevp) seems to agree it's a word...

Comment: Sneak-edited #2 in :)

Comment: It is correct :))

Answer (score 5):

Some easy ones to get started:

3

> SPIDER / PRIDES

6

> UNABLE / NEBULA

8

> LEAPT / PETAL

10

> ROCKETS / RESTOCK

11

> STRUCK / TRUCKS

15

> THIN(k) / HINT

20

> NAILS / SNAIL

Comment: All of them are correct! Great start! $(+1)$

Answer (score 3):

More answers (from the unsolved questions):

4

> NOMINATOR IF / INFORMATION

5

> GREEN / GENRE

7

> COSMIC / COMICS

13

> NEW YORK TIMES / MONKEYS WRITE

2 (not sure but worth a shot)

> DNE (does not exist)

Comment: nice catch on number 13

Comment: @user477343 did you mean "everything is correct except..."?

Comment: @jafe hahah woops, yeah I did

Comment: Everything is correct except for the last part. Think exactly why I have written it like end instead of "end" :D