# I was inspired to create a third (and not final) anagram puzzle

Tags: word, anagram

***Inspired by @[QuantumTwinkie](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/34530/quantumtwinkie)'s anagram puzzles.***

---

First one to answer all of them correctly will get the tick! Good luck!$\;\color{green}{\checkmark}$

Partial answers are also welcome :)

> 1. The _____ felt the paint on his bike. It was much _____ than the day before, so he finally took it for a spin.
> 2. "And then, right when mum ____ him into bed, a ____ of wind blows through the window and blankets fly everywhere!" she laughed.
> 3. Who were the characters ____ring in *Ratatouille*?  Well, obviously, a bunch of ____.
> 4. They were crazy, ______ ___, ready to head off for the adventure, before they all scrapped the idea and replied to the email with one word: "_________".
> 5. But the ____ ___ that had the _______ cheat sheets, was hidden in Joseph's locker... though nobody said anything because they all got A+ in maths for the first time.
> 6. Sadly, he never made it to his brother's _______ because the ____ ___ out and he couldn't drive anymore, but he still mourned his death.
> 7. She found him quite ________ when she saw him ________ in the parade.
> 8. That _____, I crept out of bed thinking that everyone was asleep... until I saw some_____: a pair of yellow eyes staring at me from outside my window.
> 9. She knew I wouldn't like the movie — it was so scary! (I think it was called "The ____".) But what was even scarier, was when she ____ned at me and turned off the lights...
> 10. I knew he was an expert at surviving out in the woods — he even knew how to build a ____ that could actually float! But what I didn't know was that he would let out a huge ____ every ten minutes. They smelt so bad, I couldn't sleep in the tent anymore.
> 11. The wooden planks holding the mattress of the bed ____ped when he jumped on it, just like I predicted. His ____ would now have to take place on the couch.
> 12. My grandpa calls flight engineers "______" and ______ engineers "seamen". But why do the words have to end with "men"? Women work, too.
> 13. When my sister noticed that the ________ were each not wearing a name-tag, she thought they were ________. That made me wonder whether or not there exists a person who has no name...
> 14. ____ _______ in famous tales and myths kill dragons, unlike David, who killed Goliath. But why? Dragons don't exist! I bet you there is not one dragon-like creature in the entire _____ ______. With such advanced technology nowadays, we should have found one by now!
> 15. His ______ parents were found dead in the ______. "Slenderman *does* exist," he muttered. "Now the question is: where are my *real* parents?"
> 16. Her ______s pretended to be proud of her when she got the job of a surgeon. Deep down, they weren't at all — they found the job absolutely disgusting, especially after hearing that her first medical procedure would involve ______ning a person's skull!
> 17. The character in the game wears these special _____ that give you a _____ to make you jump higher, a bit like Barry in *Jetpack Joyride*, except there is no jetpack.
> 18. When I looked at her new pair of _______s, I got jealous and started to become _______ at myself. Why couldn't I have those? But then I thought that perhaps if I wore them, people would notice my big ears, which is definitely not what I wanted.
> 19. _ ____ trees, especially the _____ ones. They always provide a cool shade in a hot day, and they make me think of piece — but I would never *hug* a tree! Ugh.. yuck. Imagine getting sap or ants all over your fingers.
> 20. He goes to church every Sunday, but he can't stand the sound of the _____. Every time it starts playing, he would just _____ and cover his ears.

---

Edits do not change any answers (unless requested); they just improve grammar.

Also, @[Eutherpy](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/21993/eutherpy) found a solution to 2, that is not the original. Thus, there are two solutions to that. The same applies to how @[Kevorobin](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/51276/kevorobin) found a solution to 14.

Comment: [My previous (second) anagram puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/69100/i-was-inspired-to-create-another-anagram-puzzle) and [my first one](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/68998/i-was-inspired-to-create-an-anagram-puzzle), if you have not looked at those already and/or feel interested enough :)

Comment: Is #4 eight or nine letters?

Comment: @jafe nine letters. Thanks for picking up my mistake :)

Comment: In 16, shouldn't the first blank be 6 spaces with an "s" on the end? The second blank is 6 spaces.

Comment: @HughMeyers no, but if you found a solution to 6 with an "s", you can post it as an answer. I can't upvote because I have reached my daily voting limit, but I will count it as an alternative :)

Comment: Is 14 one word or two?

Comment: @Eutherpy 14 is two words. Those types are one of the harder ones. For example, see 16. in [this anagram puzzle of mine](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/68998/i-was-inspired-to-create-an-anagram-puzzle?noredirect=1&lq=1). If 14 remains a bit too hard, I will offer a bounty reward for the user who solves it :)

Comment: ....I can favourite my *own* post? I just noticed that out of curiosity... weird, heh

Comment: Nice puzzles, glad somebody's found an answer for 4. Could you clarify 16 - the 7 letters to 6 shift? I think it works fine as 6 to 6, nf n fvathyne cnerag (Rot13)

Comment: @Alzinos you were correct. Sorry, I was supposed to put an "s" as a plural in the 7-letters part (a common mistake of mine in this anagram puzzle, I have found) but after reading through your Rot13 message, your solution works fine, too :)

Comment: Yay! Another, I love these! :D

Comment: I think this puzzle would be better if each anagram was a standalone word. So, for example, #3 could be changed to *What characters will ______ in Ratatouille 2?* (or something like that).

Comment: @J.R. okay, thank you for your suggestion. What ou like me to include the line in the post?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1.

> rider / drier (@jafe)

2.

> urges / surge

3.

> star / rats

4.

> driven men / nevermind

5.

> real bag / algebra (@Alzinos)

6.

> funeral / fuel ran

7.

> charming / marching

8.

> night / thing

9.

> Ring/ Grin(ned) (@Shahriar Mahmud Sajid)

10.

> raft / fart :D

11.

> snap / naps (@jafe)

12.

> airmen / marine (@jafe)

13.

> salesmen / nameless (@jafe)

14.OMG

> most slayers / solar system

15.

> foster / forest (@Shahriar Mahmud Sajid)

16.

> parent(s)/trepan(ning) (@Hugh Meyers)

17.

> boots / boost (@Shahriar Mahmud Sajid)

18.

> earring / angrier

19.

> I love / olive (@jafe)

20.

> organ / groan

Comment: You got all of 'em correct! Well done! (I see you liked 10.) :D

Comment: 2. is not correct... but it can be an alternative, so I will accept that :D

Comment: Regarding 14... (drumroll)... you got it correct!

Comment: @user477343 That was tough :D

Comment: I hoped that the "David and Goliath" mention would serve a clue :)

Comment: @user477343 I think we're done :)

Comment: 4. is also correct. Lemme double check the answers now.... **Edit:** okay. Include the answers to the other anagram lines, crediting the other users who found them (or continue with it, if you haven't looked at any of the other answers); and once they are *all* correct, you will get the tick! Nice job!!

Comment: Holy moley number 14. Nice work!

Comment: @user477343 Here it is, and please feel free to make one of these again, this was super fun :D

Comment: Sorry I couldn't reply sooner; I went to sleep shortly after you completed your answer. But now... I'm awake, and even better.... you get the tick! Congratulations! $\;\color{green}{\checkmark}$

Answer (score 6):

2 (Alternate)

> tugs/gust

16 (Not sure - first blank has 7 spaces, second has 6)

> parent(s)/trepan(ning)

Comment: Yes, correct! You got it, including the original for 2. :D

Comment: For 2, the actual phrase is "tuck into bed" (or 'tucks') not tug

Comment: @Perchik I was picturing the child as being reluctant, hence needing to be dragged or pulled.

Comment: Ah okay, fair enough ;)

Answer (score 5):

1.

> The RIDER felt the paint on his bike. It was much DRIER than the day before, so he finally took it for a spin.

11.

> The wooden planks holding the mattress in the bed SNAPped just like I predicted when he jumped on it. His NAPS would now have to take place on the couch.

12.

> My grandpa calls flight engineers "AIRMEN" and MARINE engineers "seamen". But why do the words have to end with "men"? Women work, too.

13.

> When my sister noticed that the SALESMEN did not have a nametag, she thought he was NAMELESS. That made me wonder whether or not there does exist a person who has no name...

19.

> I LOVE trees, especially the OLIVE ones. They always provide a cool shade in a hot day, and they make me think of piece — but I would never hug a tree! Ugh.. yuck. Imagine getting sap or ants all over your fingers.

20.

> He goes to church every Sunday, but he can't stand the sound of the ORGAN. Every time it starts playing, he would just GROAN and cover his ears.

Comment: Correct! Good start! :D

Comment: Since I sneak-edited 5 more in, we'll assume the above comment applies to them as well. No take backs!

Comment: Yes, that is true :)

Comment: @user477343 Is #13 correct like that? I was wondering because the first word is in plural form but the sentence says "he", not "they". But that was the only way I could get the anagram to work...

Comment: It is supposed to be "they". I guess it was a typo of some sort and autocrrected to "he". Sorry about that. Thanks for picking up my mistake... or perhaps I was rushing it :)

Answer (score 5):

9.

> Ring/ Grin(ned)

15.

> foster/forest

17.

> boots/boost

Comment: Yup. They are all correct! Good job! :D

Answer (score 5):

5 - fits somewhat, these are filler characters to hit the lower limit

> real bag, algebra

Comment: Yeah, that's it. I couldn't think of anything else. If you don't like the sentence, you can request for a 21st line if you want. Also, congratulations on your very first answer on the **Puzzling Stack Exchange (PSE)**! Since you are new to this site, I suggest you visit the [Help Center](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help) and browse through the sections (mainly the *Asking*, *Answering* and *Our model*). But, I don't strongly recommend it because I feel you are familiar with the stack exchange by a look of your 100+ bonus reputation as you are trusted user in the community. Keep it up :D

Answer (score 1):

17

> Sorry, didn't notice the other answers

14 (Alternate)

> Saint George, Region State

Comment: 17. was found by @ShahriarMahmudSajid in [his answer above](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/69630/i-was-inspired-to-create-a-third-and-not-final-anagram-puzzle/69633#69633), and 14. is incorrect, but that can serve an alternative, so I will accept that. Nice thought! :D