# I was inspired to create a fourth

Tags: word, anagram

It's here. 
 It's finally here. 
 It's...

> ...the fourth anagram puzzle!

Once again, heavy thanks to @[QuantumTwinkie](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/34530/quantumtwinkie) for first making these kinds of puzzles, and here is [my previous one](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/69630/i-was-inspired-to-create-a-third-and-not-final-anagram-puzzle?noredirect=1&lq=1) if you are interested but have not seen it already.

Partial answers are welcome :)

> 1. The baby loves to _____ toys so much, he often wrecks them, which sadly decreases their _____.
> 2. People always _______ him for not having a home. One said, "There's no lights to turn on at his place; it's ______."
> 3. I have a home, but people call me ____s, too. They are so ____. Sometimes, I go to bed praying to God to make them die, but I don't say ____ because I know God will never do that.
> 4. The priest always says, "You can only be _____ from a warm _____." That's why Jesus washed himself in the River Jordan, I suppose.
> 5. She was ____ ____, but after the curse was lifted, she grew back to normal, although she still likes war and ________.
> 6. The priest also says that if you do not ____ ___, then the only thing you would say to Him on Judgment Day is "_______". That priest is starting to scare me, now...
> 7. "A large ____ _____ a swamp in the _________. Who did I describe? Obviously, Shrek."
> 8. "Let's get back to my ________," he said. "I'm sure we'll find some ___ _____ there! I mean, *this* town is so bland."
> 9. "Mum, can I please go to the ______? There's a new movie coming out:  'Lavawoman VS ______'! I really want to see who wins, because it isn't revealed in the comics!"
> 10. There was a ______ of _____ to weave, so she had to buy some. Why does she like to knit so much, anyway?
> 11. "Hello! We are ___ __________, here to ______ _______. And I must say, you look like quite the thief to us, actually... I mean, we saw you steal her wallet."
> 12. She was _____. Plants *do* need water, and it is just the cacti that do not need much of it. None of them have _____, now.
> 13. He _____ her so much, he planned his assassination. "Her _____ will be my cure," he grinned.
> 14. "Politics teaches you to lie, son!" my Grandpa said. "If you ever get into __________, you will be associating yourself with _______ ___."
> 15. "I have a joke!" "Okay, tell me." "What does a ________ need in order to throw cards for a card trick?" "What?" "_____ ___!" <sub><sup>This is my favourite anagram I found.</sup></sub>
> 16. Jimmy gave her the weapon to use. "Aww, _____ ___," she said. But Jimmy was serious. "You have to ____, ____?" he said. "It's either that, or you die. No fun and games, here."
> 17. The teacher has the most talkative class. Everyday, the students' ______ ____ __ about all these kinds of ridiculous things. He couldn't even have a ____________ over the phone when another teacher called him!
> 18. "When you ____ chicken, what happens to its ____?" she wondered.
> 19. Her birthday is, believe it or not, on the 4th __ ____! But sadly, it is one of the only times she ever feels ______.
> 20. "Could you pass me the ____, please?" "Again? Mate, how much do you want? Guests will be arriving shortly, so this is the ____ pinch you'll have."

And the legendary Michael Jackson was buried on this month, so I will make one more as tribute.

> 21. "Heal the world; make it a better place, for you and for me and the entire human ____. There are people dying! If you ____ enough for the living, make it a better place for you and for me."

And another one to make up for this delayed puzzle (a little hard).

> 22. A new horror movie came out called, "The Nun". It is ironic because the movie _______ ___ even though it revolves around a nun. A nun! One of the most saintly kinds of women on this planet! In fact, the movie contains no ___________ whatsoever.

---

Apologies for the delay! My original progress did not save (I forgot to put it on autosave) and then I got caught up with Riley Riddles.

**Edit:**

I might as well make another. This one is really silly.

> 23. I had to ______ my nose so the chefs could show me their secret ______. Funny that, since none of them have nose-rings...

And perhaps another one. This is my last one I will edit, before I move on to a fifth. I'm just curious to see how many anagrams I can find :P

> 24. "C'mon, you can do it!" he shouted from the other side the gap. "Run up and ____ as far as you can. You'll make it!" But Bobby was ____ with fear, and was ready to turn back.

Okay, this is it. No more. Fifth anagram puzzle on its way.

> 25. The house was totally _______. Never again am I letting my son invite his friends over. Look at the mess I have to clean up! This is going to be the _______ job, ever...

Comment: Hurray another! :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Partials to start with:

1

> Throw, Worth

3

> Name(s), Mean. Amen

5

> made tiny, dynamite [From @kayzeroshort]

6

> obey god, goodbye [From @kayzeroshort]

7

> Ogre owned, Greenwood

8

> Hometown, Hot women

9

> Cinema, Iceman

10

> Dearth,Thread (From @kayzeroshort)

11

> The detectives, Detect thieves [From @kayzeroshort]

12

> wrong, grown

13

> Hated, Death

14

> Parliament, Partial Men

15

> Magician, Acing aim (From @Quintec)

16

> Thank you, Hunt okay (From @kayzeroshort)

17

> Voices rant on, Conversation

18

> Bake,Beak (From @kayzeroshort)

19

> Of July, Joyful

20

> Salt, Last

21

> Race, Care

23

> Pierce, Recipe

24

> Leap, Pale

25

> Trashed, Hardest

Comment: @Shahriar Mahmud Sajid, Would you mind if I added #12 to your answer?

Comment: not at all, go ahead

Comment: 10: rot13(qrnegu, guernq)

Comment: 18: rot13(onxr, ornx)

Comment: 16: gunax lbh, uhag bxnl

Comment: Yes, they are all correct now! @kayzeroshort, you are on a roll! You can post your comments as an answer and you will definitely get my upvote :P

Comment: You only have a few more left to go. Don't give up! :D

Comment: 6 more to go, btw are the number of dashes equal to word length, if so no. 2 might need correction as the first word has 7 dashes while the second has 6.

Comment: might 2 be rot13(qrgrfg;grfgrq)?

Comment: 5: not entirely sure its right, but could be rot13(znqr gval, qlanzvgr)

Comment: 6: rot13(borl Tbq, tbbqolr)

Comment: 11: rot13(gur qrgrpgvirf, qrgrpg guvrirf)

Comment: great finds once again @kayzeroshort

Comment: Everything is correct except no. $5$, although that fits funnily enough xD

Comment: @kayzeroshort again, where’s your answer? :D

Comment: Woops. I forgot to check back at this answer. Well, Imma give you a check anyway! No. $4$ is unsolved, but I am sure you will get it. If you give up, just reply back and I will give you a hint. All the information you need can be found in that line. Congratulations! $\color{green}{\checkmark}$

Comment: is @mrdeadsven 's suggestion for number 2 correct? also a hint would be nice for $4$ and $22$

Comment: 2: rot13(grnfrq,frqngr) possibly?

Comment: 4: rot13(evfra,evafr)?

Comment: 4 looks good to me, not sure about 2 though..

Answer (score 2):

15 fixed

> MAgician and acing aiM?

Comment: Yes, that is correct! Well done, and great start! :D

Comment: @user477343 Fun fact: context. https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/46888287#46888287 (explains why I haven't fixed the obvious typoes and such ;p)

Comment: Well, you have successfully beat the challenge! :P